# Python: Processing list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a record which consists of

```
number,name,length,width,height,weight,price.
```

I have 1000 records in the same format. I would like to create a list of records.
Also, I would like to process the list and retrieve all the values of record for each item in the list applying some logic.

Comment: Did you give it a try? This seems to be an easy enough piece of code, and SO is not a code writing service website.

Comment: Hello Santosh, welcome to StackOverflow. We'll help you with any technical difficulties you're facing, but this looks more like a request to work for free. If you give us code that isn't working, we'll explain how to fix it

Comment: i'm going to assume it's a txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open('filename.txt','r')
file1=file.read().split('\n')
listy=[]
for elem in file1:
   listy.append(elem.split(','))
file.close()
print(listy)
```

This is assuming it is a txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    records = [record.strip().split(',') for record in file]
```

can you try this, hope this helps